# iOS push notification not received when screen is locked

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am using parse for push notification. Once I receive remote notification I pass it to the local notification, but issue is when screen is locked `didReceiveRemoteNotification` does not hit. I don't receive any notification.

I am using iOS8

Here's my payload:

```
{ 
    CommentId = "8082a532-2380-4af5-bb3f-d247cfca519b"; 
    CommentTitle = test; action = "com.lelafe.one4communities.Notifications.NotificationActivity"; 
    aps = { }; 
    moduleIdentifier = 8; 
    nTitle = "Comment posted by someone"; 
    postingID = "c57a3d27-cfe5-41e9-a311-98a9fd7749ad"; 
}
```

Comment: What r u using? iOS 8/7?

Comment: can you give the push notification payload thalis sending from server?

Answer (score 1):

There is one more parameter that you need to pass to your payload i.e. content-available and set its value to 1. It needs to be passed in case we wish that our app should receive notifications in the background.

The [official documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications) of parse describes this parameter as follows:

> +content-available: (iOS only) If you are a writing a Newsstand app, or an app using the Remote Notification Background Mode introduced in iOS7 (a.k.a. "Background Push"), set this value to 1 to trigger a background download.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your dictionary `aps`:

Try checking out Apple's Documentation about [The Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)

Also Quoting [*@mamills*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333637/ios-push-notifications-with-empty-aps-dictionary) answer:

> If there is no badge, no alert, and no sound specified in the
>   dictionary (for the "aps" key) then a default message will not appear
>   and it will be completely silent.
>
> Look again at example 5 in the document you referenced. aps can be
>   empty, and you can specify whatever custom data you would like as they
>   do with the "acme2" key. The "acme2" data is an example of where your
>   server's "special" payload could reside within the JSON payload.